# R: how to calculate sensitivity and specificity of rpart tree

Tags: r, statistics, regression

```
library(rpart)
train <- data.frame(ClaimID = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),
                    RearEnd = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE),
                    Whiplash = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE),
                    Activity = factor(c("active", "very active", "very active", "inactive", "very inactive", "inactive", "very inactive", "active", "active", "very active"),
                                      levels=c("very inactive", "inactive", "active", "very active"),
                                      ordered=TRUE),
                    Fraud = c(FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE))
mytree <- rpart(Fraud ~ RearEnd + Whiplash + Activity, data = train, method = "class", minsplit = 2, minbucket = 1, cp=-1)
prp(mytree, type = 4, extra = 101, leaf.round = 0, fallen.leaves = TRUE, 
    varlen = 0, tweak = 1.2)
```

[image]

Then by using `printcp` I can see the cross validation results

```
> printcp(mytree)

Classification tree:
rpart(formula = Fraud ~ RearEnd + Whiplash + Activity, data = train, 
    method = "class", minsplit = 2, minbucket = 1, cp = -1)

Variables actually used in tree construction:
[1] Activity RearEnd  Whiplash

Root node error: 5/10 = 0.5

n= 10 

    CP nsplit rel error xerror xstd
1  0.6      0       1.0    2.0  0.0
2  0.2      1       0.4    0.4  0.3
3 -1.0      3       0.0    0.4  0.3
```

So the root node error is 0.5, and from my understand that is the misclassification error. But I'm having trouble with calculating the sensitivity (proportion of true positives) and specificity (proportion of true negatives). How can I calculate those based on the `rpart` output?

(The above example is from http://gormanalysis.com/decision-trees-in-r-using-rpart/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `caret` package to do so:

Data:

```
library(rpart)
train <- data.frame(ClaimID = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),
                    RearEnd = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE),
                    Whiplash = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE),
                    Activity = factor(c("active", "very active", "very active", "inactive", "very inactive", "inactive", "very inactive", "active", "active", "very active"),
                                      levels=c("very inactive", "inactive", "active", "very active"),
                                      ordered=TRUE),
                    Fraud = c(FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE))
mytree <- rpart(Fraud ~ RearEnd + Whiplash + Activity, data = train, method = "class", minsplit = 2, minbucket = 1, cp=-1)
```

Solution

```
library(caret)

#calculate predictions
preds <- predict(mytree, train)

#calculate sensitivity
> sensitivity(factor(preds[,2]), factor(as.numeric(train$Fraud)))
[1] 1

#calculate specificity
> specificity(factor(preds[,2]), factor(as.numeric(train$Fraud)))
[1] 1
```

Both `sensitivity` and `specificity` take the predictions as the first argument and the observed values (the response variable i.e. `train$Fraud`) as the second argument.

According to the documentation both the predictions and the observed values need to be fed to the functions as factors that have the same levels.

Both specificity and sensitivity in this case are 1 since the predictions are 100% accurate.

Comment: Thanks. But if the predictions are 100% accurate, why is the root node error 0.5?

Comment: You are welcome. I do not know exactly how the root node error is calculated but I think it depends on the cross validation as well. The root node error is not the accuracy metric. The accuracy is 100% on this (easy) set with only 10 observations.

Answer (score 0):

The root node error is the missclassification error at the root of the tree. Therefore the missclassification error before adding any nodes. Not the missclassification error of the final tree.